# Laravel PHP does not show all Images / Item Uploads in Form Submit

Tags: php, laravel

For some Reason i only get 18 Images when i upload more than 18.

Does anyone have reason for that?
PHP Settings or something? I am using NGINX.

Here is the route

```
Route::post('/upload-item', ['as' => 'upload-item','uses'=>'ItemController@save_items']);
```

that a little bit of the form

```
<form action="{{ route('upload-item') }}" class="setting_form" id="item_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="file" id="item_file" name="item_file[]">
```

So if i choose 22 Images i only get count of 18 in the ItemController on save_items when i ask request for the item_file count...

```
public function save_items(Request $request)
{
   print_r(count($request->file('item_file')));
```

here i see just 18 but i choosed 22 Images

but why?

Comment: On `php.ini` there is a  `max_file_uploads`,  by default it set to 20. You can increase it. Also you may need to increase `post_max_size` limit

Comment: @EsTeAa That was it! Thanks